# Bind the Data to DataGridView in C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, sqlcommand

I have a table with `ID` and a `Name` column i want to show the one `ID` and `Name` in a `DataGridView` For Example in `Textbox` when i enter `ID` and click search button the datagridview shows the specifc record. In Search `Button` I have following Code but it gives error

```
con.Open();
Sqlcommand cmd = new Sqlcommand("Select * from Registration where ID = '"+textBox1.Text+"'")
sqldatareader reader = cmd.Executereader();
if (reader.HasRows)
{
          datagridview1.DataSource = reader.GetSqlValues()
 }
```

How can i bind the data to datagridview?

Comment: Post the error please

Comment: what is the error and if you are inserting a integer value to search and your id is also numeric then why there is need of single quotes?..please your code it is more helpful

Comment: Like @NetStarter said you don't need quotes in a integer field, also you need to perform    datagridview1.DataBind(); after filling the datasource

Comment: error is that datagridview cannot show search value

Answer (score 1):

Instead of data reader use `dataSet`:

```
con.Open();

Sqlcommand cmd = new Sqlcommand("Select * from Registration where ID = '"+textBox1.Text+"'");

sqlDataAdapter1 = new SqlDataAdapter();

sqlDataAdapter1.SelectCommand = cmd;

DataSet ds = new DataSet();

sqlDataAdapter1.Fill(ds);

datagridview1.DataSource = ds.table(0);
```

This will help you

Answer (score 0):

```
con.Open();
Sqlcommand cmd = new Sqlcommand("Select * from Registration where ID= '"+textBox1.Text+"'",con);
sqldatareader reader = cmd.Executereader();
if (reader.HasRows)
{
          datagridview1.DataSource = reader.GetSqlValues();
 }
```